# Editing in Django admin reversed depended by foreign key

Tags: django

How in class QuestionsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin) implement that in Django admin in Question can see all, add, edit and delete all Answers?

```
class Answer(models.Model):
  id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
  value = models.TextField()
  correct = models.BooleanField()
  question = models.ForeignKey("Questions", models.DO_NOTHING)

class Question(models.Model):
  id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
  content = models.TextField()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Inline in ModelAdmin

In admin.py

```
from django.contrib.admin import StackedInline


class AnswerInline(StackedInline):
    model = Answer
    extra = 0
    verbose_name = "Answer"
    verbose_name_plural = "Answers"


class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AnswerInline]


admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

You can also use `TabularInline` instead of `StackedInline` depending on the style.

Comment: Docs for this; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.inlines